# Qt : Unit Test with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have a Visual Studio Project and want  to write some Unit Test for it. 
I tried doing that by using a "Native Unit Test Project".
The Problem is, that when I use a QString in the Test, the Test fails with following message:

*Message: Failed to set up the execution context to run the test*

Any suggestions how I can write Unit Test using Qt?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"

#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace Test
{       
    TEST_CLASS(UnitTest1)
    {
    public:     
        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
        {
            QString a = "Test";
            Assert::IsTrue(true);
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: Your question is actually "unit testing with visual studio unit testing framework"

Comment: You might want to see https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/1657

Comment: Hi jonas, I have tried with the above example of yours and i am able to compile the unit test. These are the following changes I've done apart from copying your code. Check if your QT is built with 32 bit or 64 bit compiler. You need to set the same in Solution Platforms. You need to add include director path and the lib file path(Qt5Cored.lib) in the Project properties. To run the unit test you need to copy the Qt5Cored.dll file in the folder where your exe file is generated(After compilation).

Comment: @sonulohani submit your comment as an answer.

Comment: @UmNyobe, Okay thanks

Answer (score 4):

I have tried with the above example of yours and i am able to compile the unit test. These are the following changes I've done apart from copying your code.

- Check if your QT is built with 32 bit or 64 bit compiler.
- You need to set the same in Solution Platforms.
- You need to add include directory path and the lib file path(**Qt5Cored.lib**(for
  debug)/**Qt5Core.lib**(for release)) in the Project properties.
- To run the unit test you need to copy the
  **Qt5Cored.dll**/**Qt5Core.dll** file in the folder where your unit test dll file is generated(After compilation).

PS:- I am using VS 2015 but this doesn't matter.

Comment: I tried your solution but sadly it didn't work so far. Where exactly i have to copy the Qt5Core(d).dll? Because there is no .exe file generated because VS starts the testhost.exe when i start the test.

Comment: Hi @Jonas, tell me one thing. As you've mentioned If you use QString then your test fails. Are you sure about this? Sorry for the part where i've mentioned exe, it will be dll actually instead of exe. Meanwhile you can go through this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-write-unit-tests-for-cpp-dlls?view=vs-2017 which will tell you in more details about how to setup the test environ and run your test.

Answer (score 1):

I have also ran into this issue with Qt6 with a project created using the [Qt Visual Studio Tools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools2019) for Visual Studio 2019.

QString was one of the things popping up as an error during the build process, but there was various more errors. My solution was as follows:

1. Gone to the [Microsoft Unit Testing Framework for C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-microsoft-test-framework-for-cpp?view=vs-2019) project's Properties (right-click on solution, bottom option of the menu "Properties")
2. As mentioned in [@sonulohani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1156189/sonulohani)'s response, I had it running in x64 by default.
3. Under `Configuration Properties` > `Linker` > `General` `Additional Library Directories` I added the path to my QT installation location libs folder (for me this was `C:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\lib`) at the top of the list.
4. Under `Configuration Properties` > `Linker` > `Input` `Additional Dependencies` I added a link to all the "*.lib" files from that very same QT installation (for me, this was `C:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\lib\*.lib`) *AND* a link to the build output .obj files for the Qt project (`$(SolutionDir)<MY PROJECT NAME>\$(IntDir)*.obj` where <MY PROJECT NAME> was my project name). This second part may not necessarily be needed.
5. Copying just the Qt6Core.dll/Qt6Cored.dll as suggested by [@sonulohani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1156189/sonulohani) did not work. It was still missing stuff. So in the properties, under `Configuration Properties` > `Build Events` > `Post-Build Event` `Command Line` I added this script to copy all the Qt6 dll files to the test project .dll output directory:
   `for %%f in (C:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\bin\Qt6*.dll) do @copy /y %%f $(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\Tests\`

Now at that point I had another issue, since both my test project and my actual Qt project was dumping its files into the same output directory, and the Qt project did not like having all those dlls in there and did not run anymore. So I created the `$(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\Tests\` directory within the regular output directory, and also made this \Tests\ subdirectory the output directory for the test project (`Configuration Properties` > `General` `Output Directory`).